# How do I set one item type of list view as a header?

Tags: unit-testing

I have to create the list view which has grouped the contact name using its first letter. Now ,I want to know that is it possible to view particular item in the listview with header. I mean at a time only one group should be open. and at first all the group should be invisible. Whichever group user will tap the contact under that group should be visible, So I tried that with the current listview with header. But I am not able to do the working as I want.So is anyone had done that thing with the default listview?

Comment: will add more information later

Comment: Found example on Cascades website